# Relate control to working events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I have .net win form application , its a pretty big application , first i was using .Net original controls , than i switched to Telerik and deleted the old control and create new button , checkes etc with same name and than due to some problem reverted back to original 
.Net controls ,

i have more than **200** controls , and all my code look like this , its so mess  , is there any easy way that i can relate only working event to my control with removing _1 , _2 , _3

**mean is there any automated way ?**

using vs 2012 and .net 4

```
private void chkPk_CheckedChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code
    }


 private void chkPk_CheckedChanged_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code
    }


private void chkPk_CheckedChanged_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code
    }
```

Comment: Try Resharper. It's got shortcut keys for deleting unused methods if you use solution-wide analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's about addhandler

```
this.chkPk_1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.myEventHandler);
this.chkPk_2.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.myEventHandler);

private void myEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code
}
```

See the reference .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984308(v=vs.71).aspx